# use diskpart in c program

Tags: c

Automating diskpart commands in windows requires pointing to a .txt file that contains the sequence of commands you want to execute. I am writing a C program that needs to use this automated feature. I want to have it run completely independent of the working directory. How would I do this?

Comment: system("DISKPART"); This opens diskpart but then I wish to automate a series of commands. In windows is as simple as "DISKPART /s DskPrtAssgn.txt" where DskPrtAssgn.txt is the series of commands I want to execute in diskpart.

Answer (score 0):

Either use a fully qualified name for the file, or, with a bit more work, pass the commands from the C program to diskpart through an anonymous pipe using popen.

Example added:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    char buffer[MAXBUF];
    FILE *fp = popen("gzip -dc data.gz","r");

    while (fgets(buffer,MAXBUF,fp)) {
        /* Process line of data, here just print it out… */
        fputs(buffer,stdout);
    }

    printf ("Command exit status %d\n", pclose(fp));
}
```

Comment: I am trying to stay away from having to include any .txt files so it looks like I will have to research the usage of popen. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like popen is similar to system(). I am using system() to open diskpart, but then I want to automate the diskpart commands. How can a pass arguments to diskpart using this method?

Comment: popen is only similar in that it runs another program.  popen returns a FILE *, and has a mode parameter.  See example above.

Comment: Thank you for the example. I will play with it,although I am not entirely clear what this does. Does this create the file I need disk part to read from?

Comment: No, it creates an anonymous pipe.  In the example I have used gzip, but you would use diskpart - I did not include that in the example because I don't know much about diskpart.  Reading the FILE pointer (using fgets() in this example) will be reading the stdout from the specified program (gzip in the example).